# Combining string elements of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, join

I've got an array that at this point is `["firstname1 ", "lastname1", "firstname2 ", "lastname2", etc]`, and I'm trying to come up with a way to combine the strings such that I'll have an array of `["firstname1 lastname1", "firstname2 lastname2", etc]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), you can iterate slice of `n` elements (2 in your case).

By joining those two elements, you will get what you want.

```
a = ["firstname1 ", "lastname1", "firstname2 ", "lastname2"]
a.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
# => ["firstname1 lastname1", "firstname2 lastname2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways:

```
a = ["Shirley ", "Temple", "Oliver ", "Hardy", "John ", "Wayne"]
```

**#1**

```
(0...a.size).step(2).map { |i| a[i]+a[i+1] }
  #=> ["Shirley Temple", "Oliver Hardy", "John Wayne"]
```

**#2**

```
enum = a.to_enum
(a.size/2).times.map { enum.next + enum.next }
  #=> ["Shirley Temple", "Oliver Hardy", "John Wayne"]
```

**#2a**

```
enum = a.to_enum
names = []
loop { names << enum.next + enum.next }
names
  #=> ["Shirley Temple", "Oliver Hardy", "John Wayne"]
```

**#3**

```
fname = nil
a.each_with_object([]) { |s,a| (s[-1]==' ') ? fname=s : a << fname+s }
  #=> ["Shirley Temple", "Stan Laurel", "John Wayne"]
```